# Adding something 'before' with the pseudo element after

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help me with a problem I'm having? I'm trying to add something with the after pseudo element so that people know that they can hover on an image for content, but I'm failing horribly.

I have tried adding the below CSS to my container but it doesn't actually do anything, I don't know what I did before, but I had some kind of image showing, but that seems to be long gone now.

```
content: "\e609";
position: absolute;
top: -25%;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
speak: none;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
z-index: 1;
```

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="four columns img-overlay" style="position: relative; border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;">
    <img src="http://stuartgreen.me.uk/pontins/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/penguin-test.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
    <div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: -11px; right: -11px; z-index: 10;">
        <img src="http://stuartgreen.me.uk/pontins/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/new-posts.png">
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 50%; transform: translate(0, -50%); text-align: center;">
        <p style="display: inline-block; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35); font-family: 'Amatic SC'; color: #FFF; text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #3a3c3d; margin: 0; padding: 10px; font-size: 38px; line-height: 38px;">Featured One</p>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay">
        <h5 style="padding-top: 11px; margin: 0 0 15px 0;">Sub Title</h5>
        <p style="margin: 0 0 15px 0; padding: 0;">Featured!!! Featured!!! Featured!!! Featured!!! Featured!!! Featured!!! Featured!!! Featured!!!</p>
        <p style="margin: 0 0 15px 0; padding: 0 0 20px 0;"><a href="#">Featured Link</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just want to add something to show the user can hover over for content

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have you used `:after` on your container selector??

Comment: Yeah, I targeted img-overlay for this, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle according to your code in your question, the problem was with `top: -25%`, with this line in your css, the content was gone out of the screen edge and hence it was not visible. Check out my fiddle, is that you want?
http://jsfiddle.net/ey7hy6p0/

Comment: Yeah, except I would like it to be at the bottom, and I set the container height to 70% so only 70% scrolls up on hover, and the icon would sit at the top still, is that possible?